# A question on rearrangement of polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $ A,B,C,D$ be polynomials in $n$ variables. Is it possible to find $A,B,C,D$ such that:

> $AB+CD=AC+BD$ (All polynomials are to be unequal)

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Setting $A=B=C=D$ is one such solution.

Comment: I made an edit, all polynomials are to be unequal...

Comment: Are you considering polynomials over arbitrary rings?

Comment: Hint: ${\rm LHS}-{\rm RHS}=(A-D)(B-C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AB+CD=AC+BD$ implies $(A-D)(B-C)=0$, so there exist different polynomials satisfying the relation iff the ring of coefficients has zero divisors.